# Prolog atom_chars error

Tags: prolog

I get the following error while  using atom_chars

```
 9 ?- atom_chars(9abc,X).
 ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
 ERROR: atom_chars(9
 ERROR: ** here **
 ERROR: abc,X) .
```

Can anyone please explain why this error occurs? I need a predicate that can convert all sorts of inputs like abc, 910, abc910, 910abc and so on, into a character list. Any substitute for atom_chars for such cases?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should surround your atom with *single* quotes:

```
?- atom_chars('9abc',X).
```

Approximately, Prolog atoms can stand without quotes when they have a C identifier 'shape', but starting with *lowercase* characters (uppercase names introduce *variables*). You'll be safe surrounding with single quotes. To know if an atom *requires* single quotes around to be safely read, you can use something like

```
shape_to_read(Atom) :- format('~q', [Atom]).
```

*edit* or the simpler [writeq](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=writeq/1)/1

```
shape_to_read(Atom) :- writeq(Atom).
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is there any way or built in predicate that can covert any type of string into character lists?

Comment: I prefer [atom_codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_codes/2)/2, because it's compatible with double quoted string (really, a list of char_code). See any answer tagged  DCG

Comment: For example, I want to take user input in a sort of command line parameters like "find(abc,X)" or "find(9abc,X)" and similar. So in such a predicate "find(Input,X)", user can give any type of string as Input, and I want to store it as character list. I was attempting to covert it using atom_chars, however since '9abc' is not a valid atom, it gives an error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should analyze user request and translate, *or* require they input valid Prolog. You already require a Prolog syntax, with variables uppercase, commas, etc etc

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but we cannot expect them to input valid every time. Besides, it would be a useful functionality to have a user input string converted and stored as character list.

Comment: couldn't you apply to *entire* request: atom_codes('find(9abc,x)', L) ?

Comment: Please don't call Prolog atoms C identifiers.